# How to define Makefile target(s) when rule calls script?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying for the first time to use `make` to run a series of scripts. I have a tree dir structure like this:

```
project
├── data
│   └── run1
│       └── pass
│            ├── 0
│            ├── 1
│            └── 2
├── include
│   └── variables.mk
├── Makefile
└── scripts
    └── operations.sh
```

I have one dataset, `run1`, which has multiple dirs in `pass`, all of which hold `txt` files. The `operations.sh` script uses a method that recursively searches a named dir (here `pass`). I expect more data (`run2`, `run3` etc), and would like to be able to process them in the same way when the data is available. To this end I use `include` on `variables.mk` (not sure if this is appropriate but it works fine), defining `$(INPUT_RUNS)`, which I will simply update as new runs arrive.

I have written a test Makefile

```
include $(CURDIR)/include/variables.mk
DATA_DIRS := $(addprefix $(CURDIR)/data/, $(foreach r, $(INPUT_RUNS), $(r))/pass)
OUT_DIRS := $(addprefix $(CURDIR)/analysis/, $(foreach r, $(INPUT_RUNS), $(r)))

##targets 
all: operations_run 

##operations
operations_run: $(OUT_DIRS) $(DATA_DIRS)
  mkdir -p $</operations
  sh scripts/operations.sh $</operations $(DATA_DIRS)
```

This specifies a set of dirs (`data`, `analysis` per run). I can then make a target with which to run `operations.sh`. This works fine. But it doesn't actually use `make` properly to my mind. I want to `make` the output, and then if rerunning `make`, not regenerate the output if no part of the data or analysis has changed.

My question therefore: generally, a target is a file. The `operations.sh` script runs a method not developed by me, and has particular rules about input and output (both are dirs as seen). I would like to make the target a set of files produced by `operations.sh`. I would like it to work something like

```
%.output.txt: $(DATA_DIRS)
    sh operations.sh $< > $@
```

I think I understand how to use `%` to name the dependencies, though haven't tested this. Can I give `$(DATA_DIRS)` as dependency, while `make`ing the target files? Conceptually I have no idea where to start on that aspect.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you told us something about the changes that are possible in "the data or analysis". Do you mean that `txt` files can be added, deleted and modified, or is it more that that?

Comment: note that make is peculiar about spaces in functions. The spaces after commas will be treated as additional empty input. e.g. I think `DATA_DIRS := $(addprefix $(CURDIR)/data/,$(foreach r,$(INPUT_RUNS),$(r))/pass)` is what you intend.

Comment: @beta, in the analysis, the `txt` files are reformatted by the script which checks for 'barcode' strings and sorts lines in `txt` into one of multiple (usually 8 but up to 12) dirs accordingly. The initial input `txt` are unchanged. While I have one run currently (`run1`) I expect more but that data will be in the same format and undergo the same analysis.

Comment: @bdecaf I had included a test to echo the dirs, and that have no spaces, but it is something to bear in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rule should be like:

```
$(CURDIR)/analysis/%: $(CURDIR)/data/%/pass
   sh operations.sh $< $@
```

Basically having a rule for individual outdirs. Supposing operations takes an input and output directory.

Though that may "think" the output directory was altered for whatever reasons (think temporary files from viewer or so).  Personally I like to manually "stamp" a completion.

```
$(CURDIR)/analysis/%/.done: $(CURDIR)/data/%/pass
   sh operations.sh $< $(@:/.done=)
   touch $@
```

This will put an empty `.done` file in the outdir with the timestamp of last successful creation.

and

```
operations_run: $(addsuffix /.done,$(OUT_DIRS))
```

to run the whole set.

Comment: This method makes sense to me. Just to clarify: I presume `$(@:/.done=)` removes `/.done` from the target allowing the script to take target dir as input (nice tip). The `operations_run` target is then added to `all:` rule to make `all` aware of what to work on. I had to change `addpostfix` to `addprefix` for some reason before it would work (?!), but it does now. Can I ask, is it common to stamp a file like this? I can see myself using it as a standard when I am not using files as targets. Thanks for your help.

Comment: stupid me.  it was `addsuffix`. I will fix it in the answer. Personally I use this `touch` often when my scripts don't produce a simple result. The only downside I see is that it may get confusing.  Whether it is common I don't dare to say - I still think about it as hack.

Comment: and yes - you are right about `$(@:/.done=)`. There would be several ways to do it, but none is intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know what the real inputs of your script are, it will be difficult to tell make whether a particular target must be re-done or not. Make compares last modification times of target files and prerequisite files. Directories are more difficult to use for this analysis because a directory's last modification time has a different meaning: it changes when files are added or deleted, not when the content of a file changes. You should first understand what the real inputs of your script are and then express dependencies between output **files** and input **files**.

Note: you can tell make to build the list of directories to process with something like:

```
DATA_DIR := $(shell find $(CURDIR)/data -type d -name pass)
```

Comment: I suppose I do not know the real inputs, there are a lot of files and they vary between different runs. Once the run is complete those data do not change, however. I do know that the script will return a set of dirs, and within them there are a set of files, again once written these will not change, and can be `cat`'d together to make a single file from which I hope to proceed in the Makefile. I think that the solution of @bdecaf makes sense, as it is 'run' based in the first instance, and adding the `./done` file means the target is a file (which is sensible).

Comment: Neat tip also on using `shell` call to define extant dirs for `$(DATA_DIRS)`